# Writing stored procedure in snowflake for converting table columns from one type to another type

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowpipe

I have a raw layer where snowpipe is being used to load the data from stage to table. All columns in that table are of type varchar. Now I want to move this data from raw layer to transformed layer with columns being cast to appropriate data types.

I am specifically looking for stored procedure logic to be written which can cast these columns and move data to transformed layer.

Can anyone please help here.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Why do you specifically want to use a SP?

Answer (score 0):

Sure below are high level steps you have to perform (queries might not runnable, check the actual syntax while building).

Step #1: write a stored procedure with dynamic SQL, to join your stage table with target table using information schema, for example:

```
select 
    listagg(stg.column_name || '::' || TargetDataType,',') SelectClause,
    listagg(stg.column_name,',') InsertClause
from
    information_schema.columns stg
inner join  
    information_schema.columns tgt on tableName and columnName
order by 
    ordinalPosition
where 
    stg.table_name = 'YourTable'
```

Step #2:

Get output of above into 2 variables

1. SelectClause
2. InsertClause

Step #3: Build dynamic SQL to run insert clause

```
command ='insert into target table'|| :InsertClause
|| 'select '||:SelectClause
|| 'from stage table';
```

Step #4: execute that query